# Themes disappeared from Google Apps Mail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-themes

I've just moved my domain to Google Apps and it's all working properly apart from one thing: *Themes in Mail.*

The standard template is so dull that I really do miss my themes. I had them working for a while, but they suddenly stopped last week and I have no idea how to get them back. I've enabled pre-release features and the automatic addition of new features and some of them are there, including Labs and Offline, but Themes are no longer there.

Does anyone have any idea how to get themes back?

*Further info:*
I'm using the free version of Google Apps (until the Business version allows a mix of the $50 Business accounts and free ones). I've tested this in Safari and Firefox 4 and am running it on MacOS X 10.6 in English (I've tried both US English and British English).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug. You can [contact](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/label?lid=2a7c11589c87110d&hl=en) the support to have it solved, because you should be able to change your theme.

Here is a screenshot from my Google Apps account:

[image: google apps mail settings - themes]

Answer (score 2):

You may need to turn it on in your Apps Settings:[image]

You may also need to log out and back in after making that change for the themes preferences to show up.